# Asynchronous Base64 downloadstream to file

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, webclient

I'm trying to develop a .NET app which will communicate with a .NET Core Server app (which I did not develop). The main goal is to download a file. Since the client app will have a WPF gui, the whole download should happen asynchronously.

From reading the server app's API I know, that the repsonse to my request is a Base64-encoded String containing the contents of a file.

What I wanted to do, is to async send a request, take its response-stream, async read from that stream to a charArray, base64-decode, async write to file (see code below).

But Convert.FromBase64CharArray most often fails with an exception

> invalid length for a base-64 char array or string

Occasionally this one succeeds but the download ends prematurely (downloadedLength < totalLength)

It seems, as if the connection was closed too early, but I'm not entirly sure whether that's true.

What I tried to resolve this issue so far:

- Using streamReader.ReadToEndAsync(), decode the complete string, async write: worked, but to download 115MB around 600MB RAM were used
- Make the block of { read, decode, write } async instead of async read, decode, async write: no improvement
- No async at all: fails sometimes, but not as often as the async version
- Use FromBase64Transform::TransformBlock instead of Convert.FromBase64CharArray: didn't finish the download in reasonable time, since inputBlockSize is set fix to 1Byte (Downloading about 115MB)
- Communicating through an SSH tunnel to omit the Apache Server: Download didn't even start
- Having client and server running on the same machine: seemed to work fine

Some specs:

- Client: Windows 7 x64, .NET 4.6.1
- Server: Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4, .NET Core 2.1.4

And finally: the Code

The function that requests the file:

```
private async Task<WebResponse> DoGetRequestAsync(string requestString)
{
    var completeRequestUrl = $"{_options.StoreUrl}/api/{requestString}";

    try
    {
        RequestStarted?.Invoke(true);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completeRequestUrl);

        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        RequestFinished?.Invoke(true);

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e.Message}");
    }

    return null;
}
```

The function that handles the reponse:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadPackage(string vendor, string package)
{
    // declaring some vars

    using (var response = await DoGetRequestAsync(requestString))
    {
        var totalLength = response.ContentLength;
        var downloadedLength = 0;
        var charBuffer = new char[4 * 1024];

        try
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    using (var fStream = File.Create(filename))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var readBytes = await reader.ReadAsync(charBuffer, 0, charBuffer.Length);
                            var decoded = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(charBuffer, 0, readBytes);

                            await fStream.WriteAsync(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);

                            downloadedLength += readBytes;
                            DownloadProgress?.Invoke((float)downloadedLength / totalLength * 100.0f);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (downloadedLength < totalLength)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Download failed due to a network error. Downloaded {downloadedLength} Bytes.");
            }

            // some follow-up stuff

            return filename;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could cause the error?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I tried to implement the solution Fildor proposed. Since I do not delete the decoded contents of the secondary buffer, more memory is needed now to perform the download. But I could omit the StreamReader and read from the Stream directly. This lead to another exception:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

No matter whether synchronously or asnychronously. Seems to be a proof for my first suspicion. But still I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: I wouldn't mix Task async and Events. To report progress use [IProgress/Progress](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

Comment: Have you tried if the downloads succeed consistently using some other tool like curl? Maybe it's even your network that has some fragile connection somewhere? The server doesn't go to 100% CPU on download or something like that, neither?

Comment: @Fildor: Just tried wget for Windows. The download succeeded several times. The server tells about 12% CPU usage. Network and server seem to be ok

Comment: Hmm, then I am missing something in the code ... I suspect maybe a performance thing, because you say "Occasionally this one succeeds". So it cannot be something that's fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Fildor: I think, the problem is the same: the stream gets interrupted prematurely. But if the number of bytes read by the streamreader is a multiple of 4 (by accident), Convert.FromBase64CharArray succeeds. But the download is incomplete

Comment: According to MSDN:
_The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached._

readBytes < 0 should be impossible .. I catch exceptions, but I do not 'swallow' them

Comment: Yes, that's ok. I just reread the question ... I guess you are getting occasionally an invalid number of bytes to decode. Have you tried reading all of the data first and converting it afterwards? ~115MB sounds much but should fit into memory.

Comment: That was the very first attempt which worked fine (a fact I will mention in the question). But to download 115MB I needed 600MB RAM. Since I don't know, how big the files may become in future, I decided to write them to disc directly.

Comment: Aha ... ok. In that case: Have a second buffer you only _append_ to when reading. Then decode the first x bytes of it where x is highest number of bytes that are a valid size for base64 and <= the total size of the buffer. Then remove the decoded ones and leave the rest to be appended to in next iteration ...

Comment: I am not sure but I suspect "valid size" will be some multiple of 4 ... looking it up.

Comment: _"FormatException
The length of inArray, ignoring white-space characters, is not zero or a multiple of 4."_ - as suspected ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64chararray?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_FromBase64CharArray_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: Interessting idea. I'm going to try that. Thx in advance

Comment: Have a look into MemoryStream. It should have all you need to serve as that "append" Buffer.

Comment: An API that *only* supports producing a file as a base 64 encoded string is broken. Talk to the developer about supporting *native* binary downloads which should be *less* work for both of you.